Generate legacy Stark key pair in Python (Immutable)
I would like to convert this code in python. I have tried a lot of solutions, but none of them returned the same key pair, so here I am. How could I achieve the intended result?
const { AlchemyProvider } = require('@ethersproject/providers');
const { Wallet } = require("@ethersproject/wallet");
const { generateLegacyStarkPrivateKey, createStarkSigner } = require("@imtbl/core-sdk");


// Function to generate Stark private key
async function generateStarkPrivateKey() {
    const apiKey = 'XXX';
    const ethPrivateKey = 'XXX';

    // Create Ethereum signer
    const ethNetwork = 'mainnet'; //'sepolia' Or 'mainnet'
    const provider = new AlchemyProvider(ethNetwork, apiKey);
    const ethSigner = new Wallet(ethPrivateKey).connect(provider);

    // Create Stark signer
    const starkPrivateKey = await generateLegacyStarkPrivateKey(ethSigner);
    const starkSigner = createStarkSigner(starkPrivateKey);
    
    console.log('Stark public key:')
    console.log(starkSigner.getAddress());

    console.log('Stark private key:')
    console.log(starkPrivateKey);

}

// Call the async function
generateStarkPrivateKey().then(() => {
    console.log('Process completed.');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
});


